# create a sequence of asynchronous fetches with for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

I have some files in JSON format and their names are something like this:

chapter1.json, chapter2.json, chapter3.json , ...

I want to fetch the content of the files with Promises in javascript and show them in sequence in a HTML page. But I don't want to repeat then() method. Instead I want to use for loop. I don't want to use node.js.

Can anyone please help me how to do that? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer.

```
function get(url) {
// Return a new promise.
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function () {
        // This is called even on 404 etc
        // so check the status
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // Resolve the promise with the response text
            resolve(req.response);
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise reject with the status text
            // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
            reject(Error(req.statusText));
        }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function () {
        reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
});
}
function getJSON(url) {
return get(url).then(JSON.parse);
}
$(function () {
getJSON('story.json').then(function(story) {
    $("#message").append(story.heading);

    // Take an array of promises and wait on them all
    return Promise.all(
        // Map our array of chapter urls to
        // an array of chapter json promises
        story.chapterUrls.map(getJSON)
    );
}).then(function(chapters) {
    // Now we have the chapters jsons in order! Loop through…
    chapters.forEach(function(chapter) {
        // …and add to the page
        $("#message").append(chapter.html);
    });
    $("#message").append("All done");
}).catch(function(err) {
    // catch any error that happened so far
    $("#message").append("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
}).then(function() {
    document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
});
});
```

The story.json is:

```
{
  "heading": "<h1>A story about something</h1>",
  "chapterUrls": [
  "chapter-1.json",
  "chapter-2.json",
  "chapter-3.json",
  "chapter-4.json",
  "chapter-5.json"
   ]
}
```

This code first fetch all of the chapters in parallel and then displays them in order.